# How to add attributes in input element with Beautifulsoup

Tags: python, forms, beautifulsoup

I use BeautifulSoup to find a specific element on my html page.
I want to add an attribute "value" to this element and save it to the original html. 
How can I do this with Beautifulsoup? Right now I do this to get the whole html and find the specific element:

```
static_map = opener.open('my_url')
bs = BeautifulSoup(static_map.read())
title = bs.find("input", {"name":"title"})
```

The title looks like:

```
<input class="has-popover form-control" data-container="body" id="id_title" maxlength="255" name="title" type="text"/>
```

I want to add in this input element the attribute: value 
and then save it to the initial html.

Then I will have to send this as a post request.

Answer (score 2):

Try this instead:

```
bs.find('input')['value'] = ''#Whatever you want the value to be.
```

Because `bs.find` returns a dictionary, so to set an item in a dicionary use subscript notation.

Comment: Thanks. But how can I define that this value is for the element with "title" name?

Comment: Try `bs = BeautifulSoup('<input class="has-popover form-control" data-container="body" id="id_title" maxlength="255" name="title" type="text"/>')` since you know exactly what the element looks like.

Comment: Or maybe `bs.find('title')['value'] = ""` will work.

Comment: Hmm. But I need to save this in the initial html.

Comment: Then try `bs.find("input", {"name":"title"})['value'] = ""`

Comment: If you modify the answer based on your last comment, then I can accept it as correct. Thanks.